# How to make a class available for Runtime java command outside of package

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

I am trying to run a Java program from another Java program where both programs are not in the same package in fact not even in the same project and to begin with I had found an answer on SO, here is the code:

```
    try {
            Process processCompile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac Main.java");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Process processRun = null;
        try {
            processRun = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Main");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            printLines(" stdout:", processRun.getInputStream());
            printLines(" stderr:", processRun.getErrorStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Executing the following code gives me the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

Now I understand I have to somehow make Main.java available universally to run it from another program. I am not sure how to do this though.

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: is there a need for this other program to run as its own Java process?  if not, this is more of a dependency management issue.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks Andrew, I will take a look.. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to run a Java program from another Java program where both
>   programs are not in the same package in fact not even in the same
>   project and to begin with I had found an answer on SO, here is the
>   code:

It the class is defined in  a package you should specify it when you run the java command :

```
try {
        processRun = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Main");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Besides, if the class was defined in a package, you'd better to define it in a directory structure symmetric to the package. I said that since when you compile the class, you don't specify the path of the package of the `Main.java` file :

```
try {
            Process processCompile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac Main.java");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: It does seem to be a good solution and I did write the full path but I am calling a project that is not under my control i.e. it can be moved to another directory anytime :( I was hoping there was another work around.

Comment: Also now that I give it a full path I still get the following error:
Could not find or load main class C:\Users\nick\IdeaProjects\HelloWorld\src\Main but now the error is at 
processRun = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Main"); so basically compiling was successful but execution still fails.

Comment: the `Main` class you are running has no package? `C:\Users\nick\IdeaProjects\HelloWorld\src` is not a Java package.

Comment: No for now its a dummy project, no package. Just a java program Main.java
Also I did put full path in the .exec() as well

Comment: Yes and it prints "Hello World"

Comment: Hi David, I found the solution, I had to put
java -classpath C:\Users\nick\IdeaProjects\HelloWorld\src Main

Comment: Excellent news :) and you also specify  the classpath  in the javac command ?

Comment: No over there I just put the complete path to the class.